# Published app with a typo in the package name

Tags: android, google-play

Hi i have published an app with a wrong package name on the google play store, What can i do to remove or change the package name but want to keep the name of the app. Any tips or experiences some one can share?

Comment: Once app is published you can not change package name.

Answer (score 0):

Once you uploaded an APK the package name is set in stone. You will not be able to change it.